# Large data frames and asking reproducible questions

Tags: r

I have been attempting to post a question regarding one of my models but I'm running into issues providing reproducible data. I have a very large (22320 obs x 31 variables) dataframe in R that basically consists. Basically, it compiles data for participants who rated items over 120 trials. When I used `dput(head(td_pref_all))` with td_pref_all referring to the dataframe, I get this output:

```
structure(list(subject = c("CC_86", "CC_86", "CC_86", "CC_86", 
"CC_86", "CC_86"), age = c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18), sex = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), race = c("5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5"), 
    bapq = c(2.47222222, 2.47222222, 2.47222222, 2.47222222, 
    2.47222222, 2.47222222), event = c(84L, 23L, 117L, 55L, 113L, 
    59L), timestamp = c("9/3/20 18:52", "9/3/20 18:41", "9/3/20 18:56", 
    "9/3/20 18:45", "9/3/20 18:56", "9/3/20 18:46"), condition = c("mean", 
    "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd"), rating = c(3, 2, 3, 
    4, 3, 5), rt_ms = c(1554, 1891, 1504, 1892, 2292, 2193), 
    image = c("accordion_1", "accordion_3", "apple_01", "apple_03", 
    "asian_01", "asian_02"), trial = c(23L, 22L, 56L, 54L, 52L, 
    58L), onset_s = c(834.97, 182.762, 1094.403, 438.244, 1063.244, 
    468.646), profile_rating = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), block = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), sub_num = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
    25L), own_pref = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L), item_num = 1:6, 
    cat1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), cat2 = c(2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 
    11L, 11L), profile_rating_new = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
    PE = c(1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2), PE_si = c(1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2), pro_PE = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), mean_p1 = c(3.177631579, 2.868421053, 
    4.421052632, 4.526315789, 4.440789474, 4.0625), mean_p2 = c(2.864197531, 
    2.728395062, 4.283950617, 4.259259259, 3.956790123, 4.104938272
    ), mean_p3 = c(2.893992933, 2.657243816, 4.187279152, 4.385159011, 
    3.045936396, 2.918727915), med_p = c(3, 3, 4.5, 5, 5, 5), 
    own_pref_nan = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6), learn_prof = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), group = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

When this is run through my model, it fails because the head is only displaying one subject. I'm not really an expert in R nor Stack Overflow, so what are alternatives for producing reproducible data for asking questions in Stack Overflow?

Comment: There are plenty of tips on [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Alternatives to `dput()` include simulating data with a similar structure or using a built in data set that comes with an existing R package. It's usually not the case that all the data is needed to reproduce the problem. Often you can reduce the number of observations or variable and still reproduce the same error.

Comment: It also depends what your question is... if you are having trouble interpreting your model, then it may be a better question for stats.stackexchange. If you are having trouble plotting the results of your model, then maybe you could use a simpler model as an example. If you are having trouble because your model throws errors, then finding a small subset of data that reproduces those errors is good for asking a question - and good because sometimes you find it is a data issue. In this case, you might try splitting your data in half, and seeing if one or both halves have the error, and repeating

Comment: In addition to reading through the above link, you could try something like `dput(td_pref_all[sample(nrow(td_pref_all), 100),])` to randomly sample 100 rows from your data

Comment: And finally, another option is to share code to simulate data. If your problem is really only reproducible with lots of data, maybe you can create random data that reproduces the issue. Use `set.seed(123)` (or some other seed) so that the randomness will be reproducible, and then share code to create sample data. But in most cases this isn't necessary - usually the problem is reproducible with smaller data and in fact finding small data that reproduces the problem helps to understand and solve the problem.